# Dynamically change sort order a SwiftUI Sectioned List

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to dynamically change the sort order of a sectioned SwiftUI list.

The Core Data model consists of an `Item` Entity with a `group` and `timestamp` attribute.

[image]

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData


struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State var counter: UInt32 = 0
    @State var order: SortOrder = .reverse

    @SectionedFetchRequest(
        sectionIdentifier: \.group!,
        sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.timestamp, order: .reverse)],
        predicate: nil,
        animation: .default
    )
    private var items: SectionedFetchResults<String, Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { section in
                    Section(header: Text("\(section.id)")) {
                        ForEach(section) { item in
                            NavigationLink {
                                VStack {
                                    Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                                    Text("\(item.group!)")
                                }
                            } label: {
                                VStack {
                                    Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Sectioned List")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Button(action: toggleSortOrder) {
                        Label("Sort Oder", systemImage: "arrow.up.arrow.down")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
            newItem.group = "Group #\(counter)"
            
            counter = (counter + 1) % 3

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func toggleSortOrder() {
        order = order == .reverse ? .forward : .reverse
        items.sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(\.timestamp, order: order)]
    }
}
```

As soon as I toggle the sort order, the app crashes with the following error.
The same code with a non-sectioned list works perfectly. In UIKit applications there was a possibility to set `tableView.beginUpdates()`and `tableView.endUpdates()`. Is there any similar functions available in SwiftUI?

```
2022-01-24 22:09:17.323096+0100 SectionedListSortOrder[69887:2007668] *** Assertion failure in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _computeRowUpdates], UITableViewSupport.m:568
2022-01-24 22:09:17.347996+0100 SectionedListSortOrder[69887:2007668] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView internal inconsistency: encountered out of bounds global row index while preparing batch updates (oldRow=8, oldGlobalRowCount=8)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203feba4 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff201a1be7 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x00007fff20753aa2 _userInfoForFileAndLine + 0
    3   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff252fd8d8 -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport initWithTableView:updateItems:oldRowData:newRowData:oldRowRange:newRowRange:context:] + 7526
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff25286d98 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 14161
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff252a1b58 -[UITableView endUpdatesWithContext:] + 116
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff252a1d42 -[UITableView _performBatchUpdates:withContext:completion:] + 277
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff252a1e35 -[UITableView performBatchUpdates:completion:] + 109
    8   SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c8b272c $s7SwiftUI25UpdateCoalescingTableViewC19performBatchUpdates_10completionyyycSg_ySbcSgtF + 378
    9   SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c8b2805 $s7SwiftUI25UpdateCoalescingTableViewC19performBatchUpdates_10completionyyycSg_ySbcSgtFTo + 175
    10  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d29fa4f $s7SwiftUI26UITableViewListCoordinatorC06updatecD0_2to11transactionySo0cD0C_xAA11TransactionVtF14performUpdatesL_yyAA0E14CoreDataSourceRzAA16SelectionManagerR_So0cD4CellC0R0RczSo0cd12HeaderFooterD0C0sT0Rcz0P5ValueQy_AVRtzr0_lF + 1638
    11  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5cb3575b $sIeg_ytIegr_TR + 12
    12  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d2a69b6 $sIeg_ytIegr_TRTA + 17
    13  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d2a70f4 $sIeg_ytIegr_TRTA.56 + 9
    14  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5cb0f304 $s7SwiftUI6UpdateO3endyyFZ + 484
    15  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c901e69 $sSo9NSRunLoopC7SwiftUIE14flushObserversyyFZ + 148
    16  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c901dd3 $sSo9NSRunLoopC7SwiftUIE11addObserveryyyycFZySo05CFRunbF3RefaSg_So0gB8ActivityVSvSgtcfU_yyXEfU_ + 9
    17  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c8fa762 $ss5Error_pIgzo_ytsAA_pIegrzo_TR95$sSo9NSRunLoopC7SwiftUIE11addObserveryyyycFZySo05CFRunbF3RefaSg_So0gB8ActivityVSvSgtcfU_yyXEfU_Tf3npf_n + 14
    18  libswiftObjectiveC.dylib            0x00007fff5981b03c $s10ObjectiveC15autoreleasepool8invokingxxyKXE_tKlF + 44
    19  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c901dc2 $sSo9NSRunLoopC7SwiftUIE11addObserveryyyycFZySo05CFRunbF3RefaSg_So0gB8ActivityVSvSgtcfU_ + 35
    20  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c901ec5 $sSo9NSRunLoopC7SwiftUIE11addObserveryyyycFZySo05CFRunbF3RefaSg_So0gB8ActivityVSvSgtcfU_To + 43
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2036bc67 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2036648c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 541
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20366a3c __CFRunLoopRun + 1126
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203660f3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff2c995cd3 GSEventRunModal + 139
    26  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff25059f42 -[UIApplication _run] + 928
    27  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2505eb5e UIApplicationMain + 101
    28  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d0d5dcf $s7SwiftUI17KitRendererCommon33_ACC2C5639A7D76F611E170E831FCA491LLys5NeverOyXlXpFAESpySpys4Int8VGSgGXEfU_ + 196
    29  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d0d5d09 $s7SwiftUI6runAppys5NeverOxAA0D0RzlF + 148
    30  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5cabdbad $s7SwiftUI3AppPAAE4mainyyFZ + 61
    31  SectionedListSortOrder              0x00000001067427fe $s22SectionedListSortOrder0abcD3AppV5$mainyyFZ + 30
    32  SectionedListSortOrder              0x0000000106742899 main + 9
    33  dyld                                0x0000000106989ee9 start_sim + 10
    34  ???                                 0x00000001137d14fe 0x0 + 4621931774
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/sven/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SectionedListSortOrder-dshdfdnljbwqiycciapdzuwjwaeh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/sven/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SectionedListSortOrder-dshdfdnljbwqiycciapdzuwjwaeh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView internal inconsistency: encountered out of bounds global row index while preparing batch updates (oldRow=8, oldGlobalRowCount=8)'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 783.5 - Device: iPhone 13 (C0D62BCF-AF61-4D92-8685-9E962DF75239) - Runtime: iOS 15.2 (19C51) - DeviceType: iPhone 13
```

Comment: You could try the trick from wwdc 21 where they first copy an items reference. Eg let items2 = items then items2.sortDecriptor = …

Comment: Or it might be because of the button causing 2 state changes. Maybe try making the button just toggle a bool for the order then use onChange to update the sort descriptor using the bool for reverse or not.

Comment: I checked if the button causing 2 state changes. That's not the case. It is changed only once. Do you remember in which session they showed that trick with the reference. For it seems not to work. Same crash and error message as before.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10017/ at about 25mins. Did you try doing it in onChange?

Comment: Yes, I also added the onChange method, but still the same error. It only works if all sections have the same number of cells. Could this be an issue?

Comment: I've never seen '!' in a keypath before: sectionIdentifier: \.group!

Comment: I use \.group! because Xcode generates optional entity attributes for the core data model. If I have a flat list or sections with the same number of cells the code works in general. I think it is somehow related sections containing different number of cells.

Comment: I further investigated the issue. It seems that the `sectionIdentifier` keyPath must be equal to the `sortDescriptors` keyPath. If so, the mechanism in https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10017/ works. If not, the app crashes with the error shown above. The dynamic reconfigure seems to be very limited.